# How to implement an "echo" like program in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

I wish to write a program main such that when I run the program, it will print :

```
>>./main 
hello! please enter text:
>> hi
hi
>> apple
apple
>> quit
quitting
```

How to do it in C++?

Comment: check `std::getline`

Comment: Did you try writing it? It's about ten lines of code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fairly basic:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    char buffer[256];

    std::cout << "Hello! Please enter some text:\n>> ";
    while (std::cin >> buffer) {
        std::cout << buffer << std::endl;
        std::cout << ">> ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You could improve on this by allowing for an infinite buffer, but you get the general idea.

Alternatively, using `std::string`. Better since you don't have to worry about the size of the buffer:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string buffer;

    std::cout << "Hello! Please enter some text:\n>> ";
    while (std::getline(std::cin, buffer)) {
        std::cout << buffer;
        std::cout << ">> ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'd use a `std::string` and `getline` instead

Comment: There are many ways to skin a cat. ;)

Comment: but if you `cin >> buffer` you end up loosing some skin ;) And replace `#import` by `#include`. `#import` seems to be a gcc extension (of which I had no idea exists)

Comment: Yeah, a habit from Objective-C. Updated.